# Medium Growing Hierarchy

Tags: proof-theory

I want to bound some functions using the fast-growing hierarchy, but for accounting reasons it looks like it's going to be easier to deal with a modified hierarchy that grows at "$1/\omega$-th" the rate: my first guess at the hierarchy I want is

- $f_0(x)=x+1$
- $f_{\lambda}(x)=f_{\lambda[x]}(x)$
- $f_{\lambda+n}(x)=f_\lambda^n(x)$

Has this, or perhaps some more carefully thought out version, appeared in the literature?

Comment: your second and third rules are only for limit ordinals?

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes.  (Though I'm not wedded to these precise rules, which seem very slightly wonky in ways I'm having trouble placing; one of the reasons I'm asking is that someone may have gotten them right and saved me the trouble.)